# Post and redirect together in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I am trying to post data and also redirect to the page at the same time. Is there a possibility to post the data and also redirect to that page?
I am able to post the data but unable to redirect to that page. I don't want redirection in the success of the post.

```
  return this._http.post('/Tickets/Search', 'body', { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Jquery implementation:

```
    function ShowDashboard(jqlJson)
    {
        post("http://localhost:22541/ServiceDesk/Ticket/Dashboard", jqlJson, "post");
    }
    function ShowDashboard1() {
        var jqlBody = {};
        jqlBody["jql"] = "project = PIMCO and  reporter = ssolairajan";

        post("http://localhost:22541/ServiceDesk/Ticket/Dashboard", jqlBody, "post");
    }

    function post(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post";

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        for (var key in params) {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to finish the post, and then redirect.
But you can do almost whatever you want.

I imagine that the caller of this function :

`return this._http.post('/Tickets/Search', 'body', { headers: this.getHeaders() })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}`

should subscribe to execute the post request and then the caller must call

`router.navigate(['/Tickets/Search']);`
in order to redirect.

Let's assume your function is called makeASearch(search: string)

`function foo(searchQuery) {

```
/*Execute the post*/

this.makeASearch(searchQuery).subscribe();

/*Redirect to /Tickets/Search obviously you should have the route defined*/

this.router.navigate(['/Tickets/Search']);
```

}`

With this, the post request will execute and right after you'll be redirected to /Tickets/Search

Tell me if it helps you.

Tip :
The trap with router and async is that if you call router.navigate before executing all your post requests you can't be sure that they'll be executed since angular will destroy your component while redirecting you.

Comment: In my case I need to post to a different application(not angular2)  with data and route to that page. The angular2 application and other application sits in the same platform. So basically, in one call, I should be able to  post the data and redirect.

Comment: I added the jquery implementation in the question, but I am trying to see the possibility in Angular2.

Comment: Try with window.location.href = "Tickets/Search" 
that should work

Comment: I don't know how jquery redirect, but it might be two requests called on calling form.Submit(). 
Or there are some http headers that redirect when doing a post.